# A way to produce inner radial shadow hover image with svg

Tags: html, css, svg, effect, adobe-illustrator

I'm looking for a way to produce an inner radial shadow hover any image with css and svg (or other ?).
[Here is an example of what i would like to do (for header and footer parts)](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/41613/screenshots/3532364/attachments/783904/full_size.jpg)

Have you got any suggestions ? I would like a way the most cross browser as possible.
Thank you !

Comment: Check this out, shows you the ropes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-radial-gradient/

Comment: CSS Gradient Generator:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thank you staypuftman, I would try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```css
body{background:black;}
svg{height:100vh; display:block; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
    <radialGradient id="rg" cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5">
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <mask id="mascara">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" fill="url(#rg)"></circle>
  </mask>
 </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" height="240" width="250" style="mask: url(#mascara)"></image>
</svg>
```

You may need to detect the position of your mouse and use it as the center for the mask.